# ngx-bootstrap timepicker (2.0.3) shows different values on ios vs Android and PC

Tags: ios, ngx-bootstrap

I am seeing different values on iOS (Safari and Chrome) than on Android or PC. My HTML is

```
<timepicker id="fromDatePicker" (keyup)="writeTime($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="event.durationFrom" [showMeridian]="ismeridian"
    [minuteStep]="1"></timepicker>
```

And in typescript I create a Date from a UTC string

```
this.event.durationFrom = new Date(event.calEvent.end.format());
```

On PC/Android the value displayed for Hours is the same as the UTC hours but on iOS the hours displayed is offset by the default timezone offset. This results in different data being saved. is there any way to force the iOS implementation to use UTC or ignore timezone?

Comment: It appears the issue may be coming from the format method in the moment library returning different data on ios and not a timepicker issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with ngx-bootstrap or the timepicker module. The problem was my fullcalendar library and its moment library were ending with different date values on ios. I am not sure how best to deal with this problem although I did create a workaround.

```
  setDateForTimePicker(calMoment) {
    let utcDt = new Date(calMoment.toISOString(true));
    let assetDt = new Date(calMoment);
    if (utcDt.getHours() != assetDt.getHours()) {
      return new Date(
        assetDt.getTime() + assetDt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
      );
    } else {
      return new Date(utcDt.getTime() + utcDt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
    }
  }
```